# "The Lakers have been winning in a row"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, idiomatic-language, grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-phrases

I wonder if we can say, "in a row" without specifying how many times in a row. For example, do you think sentences like the ones below can be said by native speakers?

> **The Lakers have been winning in a row.** *Context: The lakers won their last four games*

> **We need to win in a row if we want to be the champions.** *Context: A sportsperson talking about their team needing to be consistent*

> **The singer said the concert ended, but they surprisingly played songs in a row as an encore.** *A member of the concert audience telling his friend about a concert at which the band played at least two songs consecutively although the concert ended*

I am more used seeing *"in a row"* with numbers/quantifiers like in, *"two times in a row,"* *"many times in a row"* etc. So that is mainly why I am asking this question.

Comment: I would expect to see a number or quantifier (five times, or several times) with *in a row*. I don't think it's idiomatic without one.

Answer (score 1):

When using in a row, a quantifier (such as a number, or a statement) needs to be used. Using you examples:

> **The Lakers have won** *four times* **in a row.**

> **We need to win** *many times* **in a row if we want to be the champions.**

> **The singer said the concert had ended, but they surprisingly played**
> *several* **songs in a row as an encore.**

The important part is the italicized *quantifier*.